# APP_BASE_HREF causes *.bundle.js scripts to not load

Tags: angular, svg, webpack, angular-cli

I am trying to get SVG gradients working and from what I have seen around the net the trick is to use `APP_BASE_HREF` instead of defining `<base href="/">`. This does indeed solve the problem but it also creates a new one. If I go one layer deep `/home/test` the bundle.js scripts fail to load.

**Error**

```
GET http://localhost:4200/home/inline.bundle.js 
goals:47 GET http://localhost:4200/home/polyfills.bundle.js 
goals:47 GET http://localhost:4200/home/styles.bundle.js 
goals:47 GET http://localhost:4200/home/vendor.bundle.js 
goals:47 GET http://localhost:4200/home/main.bundle.js 
goals:47 GET http://localhost:4200/home/inline.bundle.js 
goals:47 GET http://localhost:4200/home/polyfills.bundle.js 
goals:47 GET http://localhost:4200/home/styles.bundle.js 
goals:47 GET http://localhost:4200/home/vendor.bundle.js 
goals:47 GET http://localhost:4200/home/main.bundle.js
```

It's looking for `http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js` but now that the base ref is not right it changes it to `/home/main.bundle.js`

What is the correct way to set this up?

- I don't want to use HTML5 # locations
- using `APP_BASE_HREF` breaks
  the imports as above but fixes my SVGs
- `<base href="/">` this works
  except for my SVG gradient where `url(#gradient)` now references the wrong place and can't locate my defs.

This is my setup:

app.module.ts

```
import { CommonModule, APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
```

And provided:

```
 providers: [
    {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: "/"},
  ],
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to add `--deploy-url="/"`  to command line to make it generate the correct paths to the scripts.

I.e.

```
ng build --deploy-url="/"
```